# SQL оптимизация

Tags: sql

занимаюсь оптимизацией сайта, решил начать с оптимизации запросов к бд. Нужно сделать так чтобы происходил всего лишь 1 запрос вместо нескольких.

Есть массив в котором находятся id товаров:

```
$products = ['1', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
```

Нужно достать цену для каждого товара из таблицы table_price, в ней будет id товара - id и его цена - price.

Сейчас для этого используется такая ужасная конструкция:

```
 $arr_prices = []; 
    foreach($products as $product){
        $response = $db->query("SELECT prcie as 'price' FROM table_price WHERE id = $product"); 
       if($response['price'] != null){
          $arr_prices[] = $response['price'];
       }else{
          $arr_prices[] = 'prices not found'; 
       }
    }
```

Далее используется уже массив $arr_prices. Как видите, данный способ очень не производительный, т.к. для каждого товара выполняется отдельный запрос в бд, как можно объединить это все в один запрос, при этом все данные должны быть в исходном порядке и если цена не найдена должно быть соответствующее значение?

Comment: `при этом все данные должны быть в исходном порядке` - для чего?

Comment: Для того чтобы установить соответствие между id товара и его ценой по ключу.

Comment: Наверное у вас еще есть запрос, который заполняет список товаров. Вот было бы разумно объединить эти 2 запроса в один. Почитайте про `join`

Comment: *чтобы установить соответствие между id товара и его ценой по ключу.* А кто мешает в выходном наборе возвращать не только цены, но и ИДы товаров? `SELECT id, price FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @identifiers)`

Comment: Viktorov, Нет, мне нужно именно объединить в один эти запросы, т.к. на самом деле там не все так просто, сайт большой и работает на  opencart, да и пример который я привел тестовый. Т.е. до запроса который достает id товара не добраться.

Comment: а что это за таинственное $db, которое во всех вопросах постоянно фигурирует? это объект PDO? или mysqli? или это какой-то таинственный всем известный класс?

Comment: Александр Белинский, Его метод query выполняет запрос к бд и возвращает результат.

Comment: `Т.е. до запроса который достает id товара не добраться.` - как не добраться, ведь в Вашем же запросе в таблице есть ид товара...  `FROM table_price WHERE id = $product"`

Comment: @Shillkas правильное решение тут одно - сразу составить запрос на товары с их ценами (например join). всё остальное - костыли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать конструкцию [in](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), если вы хотите за один select выбрать цены на несколько товаров.

```
SELECT prcie as 'price' FROM table_price WHERE id in ($product1,$product2, ... $productn)
```

Это будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Только так не сохранится порядок в результирующем наборе (или как минимум он не гарантирован), который так жаждет ТС.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я очень надеюсь, что ТС откажется от этой идеи так как непонятно по комментариям, а действительно ли это надо! ^)